# Differential equation for velocity regarded as a function of distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, differential-equations

Given a differential equation for velocity, $dv/dt + v = 1$, as well as its solution, is it possible to derive a differential equation for velocity with respect to distance?

I found a solution to the differential equation to be

$$v = 1 - 1/e^t$$

and since $dx/dt = v$, $x = t + 1/e^t - 1$.

From this point I have tried to use the chain rule
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx}  \frac{dx}{dt}$$
and ended up getting $dv/dx = (1 - v)/(1 - 1/e^t)$. I am not sure how to get the differential equation in terms of velocity as a function of distance.

Comment: @DavidZ See my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}v$$

So the differential equation with x as the independent variable becomes
$$v(v'+1)=1$$